# Python PyPDF2 Multiple Annotations in The Same File

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to add multiple annotations inside the same PDF.
I just wanna open a PDF and close once a time and while it opened, I would like to write multiple annotations. Bellow you can see my code.

```
def BatchAnnotate(myPDFPath, myPDFOutput, myAllNotes):

    pdf_path = myPDFPath
    reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
    
    writer = PdfWriter()
    
    for myNote in myAllNotes:

        myPageIndex = myNote[0]
        myText = myNote[1]
        myPosition = myNote[2]
        # Fill the writer with the pages you want
        myX = ConvertMM2Pixel(myPosition[0])
        myY = ConvertMM2Pixel(myPosition[1])
        
        box = reader.pages[0].mediabox

        myTotalPages = len(reader.pages)
        
        page = reader.pages[myPageIndex]
        writer.add_page(page)

        
        annotation = AnnotationBuilder.text(
            text=myText,
            rect= (myX, int(box[3] - myY), myX, int(box[3] - myY)), #(50, 550, 200, 650),
            flags=15,
            open=False,
            )
        writer.add_annotation(page_number=myPageIndex, annotation=annotation)


    # Write the annotated file to disk
    with open(myPDFOutput, "wb") as fp:
        writer.write(fp)
```

My big issue is that my script creates one page per each interaction, but when I remove the line writer.add_page(page), my script doesn't work.

You can see the error below.

```
ile "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyPDF2/_writer.py", line 2199, in add_annotation
to_add[NameObject("/P")] = self.get_object(self._pages)["/Kids"][page_number]  # type: ignore
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Anyone could help me? Please.

Comment: What does it mean _"when I remove the line `writer.add_page(page)`, my script doesn't work."_? An error message (in case post the full trace-back error)? Not the desired result?

Comment: your code is more or less good, see also the [`doc`](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/adding-pdf-annotations.html) for a similar example. `writer.add_page` is needed to build the pdf with the annotations

Comment: This code, I have extracted from documentation and adapt it to my needs.
I writer.add_page is needed, why it creates a lot of pages in my document. Where are my mistake?

Comment: Can you maybe post the whole error message?